# SQL Server management scaling

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

We are playing with a multi tenant architecture not baed on partitions but rather havings tons of databases. We decided to run some tests

Generated 5 000 database schemas, each contains ~ 100 DB objects. 250k tables & 250k other DB objects (keys, indexes) at all.

Found cons:

1. Tried to open list of tables from SQL MGMT Studio – it took ~ 10-15 min. MGMT Studio allocated ~ 700 Mb of RAM
2. DB Utilities don’t work –  tried Red Gate, DB Forge, Adept SQL Diff

Any advice when managing and running SQL Server like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [sqlcmd utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) running from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing your own management tool, targeted specifically at what you need using SMO:

[Creating SMO Programs - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162202.aspx)

That way you could simplify the program and load only what is required and potentially increasing performance.